# Infinite-dimensional normed division algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, division-algebras

Let's say a **normed division algebra** is a real vector space $A$ equipped with a bilinear product, an element $1$ such that $1a = a = a1$, and a norm obeying $|ab| = |a| |b|$.

There are only four finite-dimensional normed division algebras: the real numbers, the complex numbers, the quaternions and the octonions.  This was proved by Hurwitz in 1898:

- Adolf Hurwitz, Über die Composition der quadratischen Formen von beliebig vielen Variabeln, *Nachr. Ges. Wiss. Göttingen* (1898), 309-316.

Are there any infinite-dimensional normed division algebras?  If so, how many are there?

Comment: The infallible wikipedia states that there are only four normed division algebras over the reals, period.

Comment: Note that a normed division algebra is a composition algebra if and only if its norm arises from an inner product via $|a| = \sqrt{\langle a,a \rangle}$.  This is in fact always true in the finite-dimensional case, and I _bet_ it's true in the infinite-dimensional case as well, but I haven't checked it, so there's a slight gap here, at least in my brain.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A MathSciNet search reveals a paper by Urbanik and Wright ([Absolute-valued algebras. *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **11** (1960), 861–866](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1960-0120264-6)) where it is proved that an arbitrary real normed algebra (with unit) is in fact a finite-dimensional division algebra, hence is one of the four mentioned in the OP. A key piece of the argument (Theorem 1) is to show that such an algebra $A$ is **algebraic**, in the sense that if $x \in A$, then the subalgebra of $A$ generated by $x$ is finite-dimensional. The authors then invoke a theorem of A. A. Albert stating that a unital algebraic algebra is a finite-dimensional division algebra.

Comment: Thanks very much! By "real normed algebra" (with unit)" you mean what I'd called "normed division algebra (with unit)". (The authors actually use the term "absolute-valued algebra", which is nonstandard.) Also, when you write "unital algebraic algebra", I'd write "unital algebraic normed division algebra" - we need $|ab| = |a||b|$ in Albert's theorem. But anyway: you gave me what I wanted! And it's a very cute skinny PDF file, too

Answer (score 10):

Hurwitz's theorem is stated [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=6YG4ycpKMYkC&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q&f=false) (section 2.6 of 'A taste of Jordan algebras' by Kevin McCrimmon) as:

> Any composition algebra $C$ over a field $\Phi$ of characteristic not 2 has finite dimension $2^n$ for $n=0,1,2,3$ and is one of the following ...

it goes on then to describe generalisations of the usual normed division algebras.

The wikipedia page [composition algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_algebra) tells us that one only has a 1-dimensional composition algebra when the characteristic of the base field is not 2, but otherwise you can start from a 2-dimensional composition algebra over a characteristic 2 field and perform the usual [Cayley-Dickson construction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cayley-Dickson+construction).

Edit: The following theorem was proved by Kaplansky ([*Infinite-dimensional quadratic forms admitting composition*, Proc AMS 1953](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1953-0059895-7)), which finishes off the classification. A quadratic form $g$ on an algebra $A$ over a field $F$ in this context is a function $g:A \to F$ such that $g(kx) = k^2g(x)$ for $k\in F$ and $x\in A$.

> Theorem. Let $A$ be an algebra with unit element over a field $F$. Suppose
>   that $A$ carries a nonsingular quadratic form $g$ satisfying $g(xy) = g(x)g(y)$ for all
>   $x, y \in A$. Then: 
>   (a) A is alternative,
>  
>   (b) except for the case where $A$ has characteristic two and is a purely inseparable field over $F$, $A$ is finite dimensional and of dimension 1, 2, 4, or 8, 
>   (c) $A$ is either simple or the direct sum of two copies of $F$, 
>   (d) $g(x) = x^\ast x$ where $x\mapsto x\ast$ is an involution of $A$.

So unless your base field has characteristic 2, and your division algebra is a purely inseparable extension of the base field, your division algebra has to be finite dimensional.

Comment: Note that normed division algebras are special cases of composition algebras...

Comment:  Thanks, David. In the finite-dimensional case I know how to show that normed division algebras must have a norm arising from an inner product, and are thus composition algebras.   I would need to check this in the infinite-dimensional case. But the result you state is a very nice purely algebraic result along the general lines I sought.

Answer (score 8):

The associative case follows from Mazur's Theorem (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%25E2%2580%2593Mazur_theorem)). He proved that there are up to isomorphism precisely three Banach division algebras, namely $\mathbb R,\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb H$. This applies to the completion of any normed division algebra, which still verifies the identity $|ab|=|a||b|$, and hence is a division algebra.

Comment: The question isn't assuming associativity, so I'm not sure if Mazur's theorem still applies.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice. I changed the text accordingly.