# Is there a classification of the $p$-adic normed division algebras?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, p-adic-numbers, division-algebras

A **normed division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$** is a pair $(A,\lVert{-}\rVert)$ with

- $A$ an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra with a unit $1_A$;
- $\lVert{-}\rVert\colon A\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ a norm on $A$;

such that:

- For each $a\in A$, there exists a unique $a^{-1}\in A$ such that $a^{-1}a=1_A=aa^{-1}$;
- For each $x,y\in A$, we have
  $$\lVert xy\rVert=\lVert x\rVert\lVert y\rVert.$$

**Hurwitz's theorem** then states that the only associative normed division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, and the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$.

---

The isomorphisms classes of associative division algebras over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ [are classified](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/321519) by $\mathrm{Br}(\mathbb{Q}_p)\cong\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Is there a classification of the associative *normed* division algebras over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

(E.g. is $\mathbb{C}_p$ such an algebra? Is there a normed division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ which we could call the "$p$-adic quaternions $\mathbb{H}_p$"?)

Comment: you're using a not very standard sense of "division algebra". Following your definition, the link you're giving only addresses *associative* division algebras.

Comment: As KConrad mentions in his answer: Hurwitz's theorem only classifies the **finite-dimensional** division algebras.

Comment: YCor and Gerald Edgar, thanks! I've rewritten the question to use a more standard definition of division algebra and consider only the associative case (I didn't mention finite-dimensionality because it seems having a unit [already forces the algebra to be finite-dimensional](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45663); is this correct?). I'm mostly interested on whether e.g. there are interesting $p$-adic analogues of the quaternions (and so on), though I'm having a bit of trouble to formulate the question in a useful way...

Comment: Emily, you made a link in your previous comment to a theorem about *real* division algebras.  Theorems proved over $\mathbf R$ need not carry over to analogous structures over $\mathbf Q_p$, for instance there are only two finite-dimensional $\mathbf R$-central division algebras (the reals and quaternions), but there are infinitely many finite-dimensional $\mathbf Q_p$-central division algebras, roughly  because the alg. closure of $\mathbf R$ is finite-dim. over $\mathbf R$ but the alg. closure of $\mathbf Q_p$ is infinite-dim. over $\mathbf Q_p$.

Comment: You said you are mostly interested in $p$-adic analogues of the quaternions.  In that case there is an exact analogue between $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf Q_p$ for each prime $p$. There are exactly two $4$-dimensional $\mathbf R$-central simple algebras, namely the matrix ring ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf R)$ and the division ring ${\mathbf H}$, and there are also exactly two $4$-dimensional $\mathbf Q_p$-central simple algebras, the matrix ring ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf Q_p)$ and a division ring.  That division ring for $p=2$ is $\mathbf H(\mathbf Q_2)$, but it's something else for $p > 2$.

Comment: Now I've seen you're sticking to the associative case (and implicitly to the finite-dimensional case). My understanding is that the remaining question is whether every finite-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ admits a multiplicative norm.

Comment: @KConrad Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @KConrad, [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1042111) reminds me of my favourite experience in a job talk. Someone asked me "Could you say a word about why representation theory of groups over the $p$-adic numbers is so different from over the reals?" I said: "I'll say two words: 'algebraic closure'." (I should have said "finite-dimensional algebraic closure", but I was still pretty pleased with myself. Of course I did go on to explain!)

Comment: @LSpice as long as the person didn't think you were suggesting $\mathbf R$ is algebraically closed!  By the way, how do you tag hyperlinks to a phrase in a comment? I figured out how to do that in an answer by looking at the code in someone else's answer, but I can't do that for someone else's comment.

Comment: @KConrad, the timestamp next to a comment is, non-obviously, a link, like `https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406381/is-there-a-classification-of-the-p-adic-normed-division-algebras?noredirect=1#comment1042204_406381` for yours.  You can remove the slug and `?noredirect=1`; or, if you really want to save characters, it can be post-processed down to `https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1042204`. See also [Is linking to comments possible?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4763). Then the syntax is `[text](url)` as usual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clearly you are assuming some kind of finite-dimensionality over the center.

To classify the finite-dimensional associative division algebras over $\mathbf Q_p$, or more generally over a local field, it's standard to fix the center. A *$K$-central algebra* here will mean a $K$-algebra whose center is $K$, so $\mathbf C$ and ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf C)$ are each $\mathbf C$-central algebras, not $\mathbf R$-central algebras. And rather than say each finite-dimensional associative $\mathbf R$-division algebra (meaning $\mathbf R$ is *in* the center but possibly not the whole center) has to be $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf C$, or $\mathbf H$, it would be better to say the only finite-dimensional associative $\mathbf R$-central division algebras are $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf H$, while the only finite-dimensional associative $\mathbf C$-central division algebra is $\mathbf C$.

Associative division algebras having center equal to a local field and being finite-dimensional over the center are discussed in Pierce's book *Associative Algebras*.  Chapter 15 is on cyclic division algebras and chapter 17 is on division algebras over local fields.  Don't expect an easy method to determine which cyclic algebras are division algebras in general, but it's possible to give an easy method "in principle" in special cases.  For instance, if $A$ is an $F$-central simple algebra with $\dim_F(A) = p^2$ for a prime number $p$, then either $A \cong {\rm M}_2(F)$ or $A$ is a division ring. In practice you may need to some work to figure out if such a central simple algebra given to you in an abstract form is or is not the matrix ring.

For a field $F$, a *quaternion algebra over* $F$ is defined to be an $F$-central simple algebra of dimension $4$. An example is ${\rm M}_2(F)$, and sometimes it is the only example ($F = \mathbf C$ and $F$ finite). We call ${\rm M}_2(F)$ the "split" or "trivial" quaternion algebra over $F$. All other quaternion algebras over $F$ are division rings, and when $F$ is $\mathbf Q_p$ or any other local field there is one nontrivial quaternion algebra over $F$. Over $\mathbf Q_2$ this algebra is $\mathbf H(\mathbf Q_2)$, but for $p > 2$ we have $\mathbf H(\mathbf Q_p) \cong {\rm M}_2(\mathbf Q_p)$. A uniform description of the nontrivial quaternion algebra over $\mathbf Q_p$ for all $p$ uses a cyclic algebra construction based on the quadratic unramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$. (**Note**: there are *infinitely many* nonisomorphic quaternion algebras over $\mathbf Q$.  The contrast between that and finiteness of the number of quaternion algebras over $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf Q_p$ is analogous to the contrast with quadratic extension fields: $\mathbf R$ and each $\mathbf Q_p$ have only finitely many quadratic extension fields up to isomorphism, while $\mathbf Q$ has infinitely many.)

You could call the unique nontrivial quaternion algebra over $\mathbf Q_p$ "the $p$-adic quaternions" but that label is not standard.  It's more often called the nonsplit or nontrivial quaternion algebra over $\mathbf Q_p$.

The recent [book](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ejvoight/quat-book.pdf) by John Voight on quaternion algebras has an account on quaternion algebras over local fields in Chapter 13.

A brief account on the history of the quaternion algebra construction over fields other than $\mathbf R$ is described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156338/history-of-quaternion-algebras).

Comment: ＠KConrad Thanks!